# Gettiing Year from another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field named 'SALARY ON' in which data(year-month) entered is in format '2012-01'(datatype varchar) in table named Table1.For creating a sp i need to take only 2012 from above mentioned table field. How can I do this.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, a 'SUBSTRING' and 'CAST' will do it for you:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING([SALARY ON], 1, 4) AS INT) FROM SALARY
```

This depends in the fact that the date has been entered in the format YYYY-MM. If you're checking this in a constraint, then the above sample will be fine. Otherwise, you'll need to do some pattern checking before you try to convert it:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [SALARY ON] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' THEN SUBSTRING([SALARY ON], 1, 4) AS INT) ELSE -1 END
```

You can then take all of the years returned as -1 and raise an error to the user, filter them out, write them to a log file, etc, depending on the environment in which the sp is being called.

Comment: Thank You Mr.PETER for your kind help.This answer meet my requirements. thankyou.